# IPAD , Potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client

Tags: asp.net, ipad

In my application, there is only a login page and a report page. When the user enters his login credentials he will be redirected from the login page to the reports page. I am using forms authentication for this purpose.

On the reports page I will be displaying various reports (using Telerik reporting) based on user inputs for various fields.

Now here is the funnier part; My application works correctly in all browsers (including Safari on windows platform). But when I open it in an Ipad I am getting the below error,

*“Potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client “*

This error occurs when the forms authentication redirection happens from the login page to the reports page.

I tried a variety of solutions like setting  ValidateRequest="false" &  requestValidationMode="2.0" , but none of them helped. I also tried removing the forms authentication and that also didn’t help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous things that can cause this.  Usually it happens because you are submitting html inside an input field back to the server.

However, it can also happen under certain circumstances when view state is corrupted.  You might look at setting viewstate to expand across multiple hidden fields.

Also, you can set validateRequest at the page level to try and ignore this situation.